# Which law is this specified here?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-analysis

I am reading the book *Introduction to Reinforcement Learning* by Barto and Sutton.

Snippet from book:

[image]

What is this well-known result/law used here?

Answer (score 0):

This result is mentioned in the Wikipedia article for [stochastic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) in the section on the Robbins-Munro algorithm, although this result doe not appear in (RM51).  It does appear explicitly in (B54).  In the survey (D56), these conditions are called "Blum's conditions", but I don't see evidence in other literature of use of that phrase or any other short phrase to describe the set of conditions you quote.

(B54):  Blum, Julius R., "Approximation Methods which Converge with Probability one", Ann. Math. Stat. 25 (2): 382–386, 01 June 1954. doi:[10.1214/aoms/1177728794](https://doi.org/10.1214%2Faoms%2F1177728794).

(D56): Derman, C., "Stochastic Approximation", Ann. Math. Stat. 27 (4): 879-886, 1956.  doi:[10.1214/aoms/1177728065](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728065)

(RM51):  Robbins, H.; Monro, S., "A Stochastic Approximation Method", Ann. Math. Stat. 22 (3): 400, 1951. doi:[10.1214/aoms/1177729586](https://doi.org/10.1214%2Faoms%2F1177729586).